# Perl CGI Hook is not working as expected

Tags: perl, upload, cgi

I have problems using the perl cgi hook.

It seems that after I pressed the "send" button my perl script is not called instandly but after the file is uploaded completely.

That might be because of a server setting.

Was anyone faced with this problem before?

**Update:**

### The reason was the pre installed: Apache Security Module

Thanks for your time.

---

**Perl Source Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
use CGI qw(:cgi);
use IO::File;
use strict;

my $hook_file = "test.txt";

my $hook_handle = new IO::File;
$hook_handle->open(">> $hook_file") or die("Failed to open $hook_file: $!");

my $hook_query = CGI->new(\&hook, $hook_handle);

#start upload:
my $query = new CGI;

sub hook{
    my ($current_filename, $buffer, $bytes_read, $hook_handle) = @_;

    $hook_handle->print( join(" ",times()) . " -> " . $bytes_read ."\n" );
}



print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";


1;
```

To monitor the upload progress I am using tail:

```
touch test.txt
tail -f test.txt
```

Using a simple HTML POST form I start to upload a file of 5.5 MB.

The output is always similar:

```
system time / user time / cpu time   ->   bytes transfered

0.03 0 0 0 -> 4037
...
...
...
0.11 0.01 0 0 -> 5520894
```

Saying it uploaded 5.5 MB in 0.1 seconds.

---

**Server configuration**

There are tons of differences between the configurations:

```
use Config qw(myconfig config_sh config_vars);

print myconfig();

print config_sh();
```

Some differences: (please tell me if sth else could be interessting)

> The first value is of the working server.
>
> The second values is of the
>   bugging dreamhost server.

```
// dreamhost uses an older version of perl:
PERL_API_VERSION='10' -> '8'
api_versionstring='5.10.0' -> '5.8.0'

// dreamhost uses ByteLoader 
extensions='B ...'
extensions='B ByteLoader ...'

// dreamhost uses an older gcc version
gccversion='4.3.3' -> '4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)'

// dreamhost uses an older libc version
gnulibc_version='2.9' -> '2.3.6'

// the dreamhost server is using fast stdio
usefaststdio='undef' -> 'define'
```

CGI (**updated**)

because of Sinans advice I updated my CGI version (however it did not solve my problem)

```
// dreamhost cgi version
print $query->version (); -> 3.48
```

Comment: What webserver are you using? Apache? Lighttpd?

Comment: It is a dreamhost.com server running `Apache` - `Linux gotti 2.6.31.5-aufs2-grsec-1.0-x86_64-xeon`

Comment: To be nitpicky, it's a good idea to use strict before any other package, that way proceeding packages will also be using strict.

Comment: @squeeks `strict` is lexically scoped.

Comment: What really matters is the version of `CGI.pm`.

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but if the version of `CGI.pm` on the problematic host is lower thant `3.03`, it is missing a bunch of fixes.

Comment: dreamhost cgi version : `print $query->version (); -> 3.15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some difficulty with printing to a filehandle that is passed to the hook, presumably because of buffering issues. I decided to use `append_file` from `File::Slurp` and passing the name of the log file.

I also decided to wrap the script in a `run` sub just in case you are running this as a registry script under `mod_perl`. Finally, I do not know where the `times()` function came from, so I used `time` instead. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use CGI;
use File::Slurp;

run();

sub run {
    my $logfile = 'E:/srv/deploy/app/up.log';

    my $cgi = CGI->new(\&hook, $logfile);

    print $cgi->header('text/html'),
          $cgi->start_html,
          $cgi->p('Upload done'),
          $cgi->end_html;
    return;
}

sub hook {
    my ($filename, $buffer, $bytes_read, $logfile) = @_;
    append_file $logfile, \ sprintf("%d: %d\n", time, $bytes_read);
}
```

Output:

```
1258030571: 4051
1258030571: 8102
1258030571: 12153
...
1258030574: 5959021
1258030574: 5963072
1258030574: 5963469
```

CGI version: 3.37
apache version: 2.2.4 (Windows)
perl version: 5.10.1 (ActiveState)

Comment: Thanks Sinan!
However it doesn't work for me.
`1258031962: 4039` -> `1258031962: 5059492`
It "freezes" until the download is done and than starts to pass all byte changes at once.

Comment: There are a bunch of upload related bugs fixed since 3.13. May be you can take a look at those: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.48/Changes http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Status=Resolved&Name=CGI.pm

Comment: I am now using CGI-Version 3.48. And having still the same problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Ghommey I am stumped too. I will update if I think of anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sinan! I finally found out that the apache security module was the reason for my issue.

Comment: @Ghommey Thanks. I am glad your problem was solved. It's always the last place you look ;-)